# Linux RHEL 7 - Ansible - Execute command in shell is normal but got file not found/permission denied when run via script

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, shell, ansible

I have an Ansible body as follow

```
    - name: install
      command: sh /installScript.sh
      args:
        chdir: /home/cust/
```

then I execute my playbook using this

```
ansible-playbook -i my_inventory.ini upgradeBreeze.yml
```

in my inventory file, I put ansible_user and ansible_password.
After I ran the playbook, this had happened:

```
fatal: [host]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["sh", "/installScript.sh"], "delta": "0:00:00.010394", "end": "2023-07-25 14:35:10.108052", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2023-07-25 14:35:10.097658", "stderr": "sh: /installScript.sh: No such file or directory", "stderr_lines": ["sh: /installScript.sh: No such file or directory"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

But the problem is that, I have the installScript.sh file under /home/cust/ already, I don't get why ansible reports a failure, is there a suggestion what I should do ?

Ansible 2.9.27
Python 2.7.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your command, you explicitly state that `installScript.sh` is in the root (`/`) directory:

```
command: sh /installScript.sh
```

This is also reported by sh: `sh: /installScript.sh: No such file or directory`

For this to work, you should either specify the full path, or make it relative.

Full:

```
- name: install
  command: sh /home/cust/installScript.sh
  args:
    chdir: /home/cust/
```

Relative:

```
- name: install
  command: sh installScript.sh
  args:
    chdir: /home/cust/
```

Comment: Thank you for pointed out the problems there, also I have some struggling with the permission but I will post by another question.